# Do One-For-All users have different training experiences?

Tags: my-hero-academia

While training his successor, All Might is often surprised by Midoriya's abilities (or lack thereof) to control One-for-All. He notes things like, "I guess you can only use 5% of this power right now". 
Were All Might and previous users just more adept in adapting to this Quirk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the other successors for One-For-All were handpicked by the previous users among the fittest to use the quirk. Gran Torino mentions that even though Toshinori/All-Might was born quirkless, he possessed great resilience and endurance to maintain One-For-All power.

Midoryia had no previous training nor did he have a good constitution or muscle strength to keep up with One-For-All's great stress upon the body. That is why All-Might has often had those remarks about him.

Answer (score 1):

The body that Midoriya possessed is not a perfect vessel for one for all (at the moment). But his predecessors were better vessels. One for all is stronger for Deku than All Might. Same way, Deku and all might have stronger models of one for all than Nana Shimura. It's because one for all stockpiles power. So, the backlash also increases. Therefore, it's harder for Deku to master one for all.

Answer (score 1):

I am following the anime and the answer will be based only on that,

First of all,
like every power is unique and has different training requirements, that you can see in UA.  Similarly, Every person is unique too, much like the real world. You can define this uniqueness over a lot of different factors.

Hence, the way Deku sees things and comprehends them will be different than All Might or anyone else.
Example: Deku uses Microwave to explore his control over power which All Might never considered.

This would also conclude that their way of using power will be different, what you see in the series later is that Deku relies on Footwork and strategy whereas All Might used Punches.

Now coming to your question:

1. Since All Might got hurt, *Deku got his powers pretty early* (As, it
   was planned to be given to his super senior who had much more
   training and experience). Thus, making him unable to completely
   control his powers.  We do not know at what ages the other users of
   One for All got their powers. But they might be older than Deku when
   they gained them, thus Deku looks to be more struggling against
   them, who made it look easy probably.
2. Deku has done a lot of research, and made his own database that makes him quite *skilled in strategy and quicker in responding to difficult situations*, that too from the very beginning without any training. Which might not be possible with other users of All For One.

Thus if you say that they were skilled, you might find Deku to be Sharper. But there is a lot unknown.